# Any smart approach to finding a matrix given the characteristic polynomial?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial

> Find a matrix whose characteristic polynomial is
>   $\newcommand{\l}{\lambda}\l^6-5\l^5+3\l^3+4\l^2-\l+5.$

Given this characteristic polynomial, I tried factorizing it to obtain its roots, then work from there to find an original matrix $A$. However, here the roots seem either irrational or complex by rational root theorem, which makes this approach impossible. Are there other characteristics of the eigenvalues that I can use here to find an original matrix $A$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: Find the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial.